# I have a problem with checking my email feild

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm new to android and I created a database and I have an id as an integer primary key autoincrement
but I check on the email attribute when I register a new acc on the application, but I have a problem with the sql query that I can't put my hand on.
So I got this error today on this method that calls the name from the database using the email, and I hope you can tell me what's wrong!

```
E/MessageQueue-JNI: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT user_name FROM USER_TABLE WHERE user_email = androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{3c496d9 VFED..CL. ........ 0,0-656,127 #7f0a0068 app:id/email}
```

Here's the method:

```java
public String getName(String mail) {
    String nameReturn="Name";
    SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT user_name FROM USER_TABLE WHERE user_email = "+mail, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) nameReturn = cursor.getString(0);
    return nameReturn.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are passing the EditText view to the query. Just pass the text itself

```
editTextView.getText()
```

Comment: String cursor = dataBaseHelper.getName(email.toString());
this is how i call it

Comment: toString in this case does not return the edit text value, it is just a representation of the object. you need to call getText instead.

Comment: ok, good but now i have this problem E/MessageQueue-JNI: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "@mail": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT user_name FROM USER_TABLE WHERE user_email = khaled@mail.com

Comment: you need to 'quote' the email

Comment: Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT user_name FROM USER_TABLE WHERE user_email = +'mail'", null);
like this?

Comment: "SELECT user_name FROM USER_TABLE WHERE user_email ='" + mail + "'"

Comment: Thanks, please accept the answer if you think it has answered your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Because your condition is string. So you must set into single quote

```
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT user_name FROM USER_TABLE WHERE user_email = '"+mail +"'", null);
```

Or you can use this type:

```
        String[] args = {mail};
        String sql = "SELECT user_name FROM USER_TABLE WHERE user_email =?";
        Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery(sql, args);
```